# Open a connection where there is a password: Run-time error '-2147221241 (80040107) Automation error Unspecified error

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a database hosted on AWS RDS- MySQL database and I am trying to push the data from Excel to the database using VBA on clicking a button.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection
  con.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver};" & _
      "Server=worksheetautomation.***************.rds.amazonaws.com;" & _
      "Database=worksheet;" & _
      "User=****;" & _
      "Password=****;"
      "Option=3;"

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Application.Range("EXP")
  Dim row As Range
  For Each row In rng.Rows
       Sql = "insert into TestExperiment(Experiment_id, Experiment_Name, Experiment_Method, Experiment_Analyst, Experiment_NumSample) values (' " & row.Cells(1).Value & " ' , ' " & row.Cells(1).Value & " ', ' " & row.Cells(2).Value & " ', ' " & row.Cells(3).Value & " ',' " & row.Cells(5).Value & ")"
       con.Execute Sql
  Next row

  con.Close     
  MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

I am trying to execute this code and getting a run time error and when I try to debug the code:

> Run-time error '-2147221241 (80040107)

```vb
con.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver};" & _
"Server=worksheetautomation.***************.rds.amazonaws.com;" & _
"Database=worksheet;" & _
"User=****;" & _
"Password=****;"
"Option=3;"
```

This part is marked in yellow with an arrow on the password line.

Comment: Looking at this https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/, do you need to specify the option?

Comment: Tried writing the options but still has the same error. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the concatenation and line continuation on the second to last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below best practices in VBA:

1. Always `Debug\Compile` code after code changes. In fact, VBA should have raised or highlighted or red-lettered the syntax issue of line continuation as soon as your cursor leaves the problem line. See added `&_` below. But possibly this is a typo in your post.

   ```
   "Password=****;"  & _
   "Option=3;"
   ```
2. Use appropriate [error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm) especially when interacting with APIs like ADO that can raise runtime exceptions for more informative messages:

   ```vb
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   On Error Goto ErrHandle

         '...code...

   ExitHandle:
      Set con = Nothing  ' RELEASE ALL set OBJECTS
      Exit Sub

   ErrHandle:
      Msgbox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
      Resume ExitHandle
   End Sub
   ```
3. Use the industry best practice standard of SQL parameterization whenever you import data between application layer (i.e., VBA) and database (i.e., MySQL). Among [security](https://xkcd.com/327/) reasons, it is more efficient, readable, and maintainable as you avoid messy quotes and concatenation. In fact, your current code misses a last single quote:

   ```vb
   " ... ' " & row.Cells(3).Value & " ',' " & row.Cells(5).Value & ")"
   ```

   Most DB-APIs like ADO support [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017). Though implementation will differ beyond VBA to other languages and beyond MySQL to other databases, the core concept is the same involving a prepared statement with parameter placeholders that are later binded with literal values. Consider below adjustment:

   ```vb
   Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
   Dim rng As Range, row As Range

   Set con = New ADODB.Connection
   con.Open ...

   ' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
   sqlStr = "INSERT INTO TestExperiment(Experiment_id, Experiment_Name, Experiment_Method, " & _
            "                           Experiment_Analyst, Experiment_NumSample) " & _
            " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 

   ' ITERATE THROUGH ROWS
   For Each row In Application.Range("EXP").Rows
       Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

       With cmd 
           .ActiveConnection = con
           .CommandType = adCmdText
           .CommandText = sqlStr

           ' BIND PARAMS
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("id_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, row.Cells(1).Value)
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("name_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, row.Cells(2).Value)
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("method_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, row.Cells(3).Value)
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("analyst_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, row.Cells(4).Value)
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("sample_param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, row.Cells(5).Value)

           ' EXECUTE ACTION
           .Execute
       End With

       Set cmd = Nothing
   Next row
   ```

Comment: Thanks for all the information! This will surely help me in the future!